# What Is the TELNET User and Password for the Y4C-ZA security camera

Tags: security, port, password-recovery, ip-camera

I bought a Y4C-ZA security camera recently, I scanned all the open ports on it, and found there was a telnet port open: port 23, does anyone know what the telnet credentials would be, also, the following ports are also open, if you know what and how the following ports work/can be accessed and used, please answer with it: 554, 843, 5050, 6670, 7101, 7103, 8001.  also, port 80(http) is open, but it responds with 'No data sent' when opened in google, does anyone know if there is a way to get into port 80, or did the manufacture open it but give the camera no HTTP file that can be shown.

Comment: have you tried searching using for example google to see what those ports are? ms-rtsp, adobe flash socket policy server, mmcc, irc (and some trojans - always a good sign when buying chinee security equipment), RealAudio, RealAudio, icecast/shoutcast

Comment: also, searching for that product, came across `root`/`cxlinux` for telnet - YMMV

Comment: i did see some of the ports, but some of them i couldnt find

Comment: ok will try those credentials

Comment: I've also seen `root` with NO password

Comment: Using the cxlinux password, i get: -sh /bin/hostname: not found 

then it just gives me a command line, with # as first letter at start of each line. but no linux or windows commands work, tried ls and cd /     but they just went to newline upon pressing enter

Comment: using the ssh command on windows just gives a timeout, even when specifying the telnet port: 23

Comment: why would you use `ssh` for a `telnet` session? as far as what you can do after logging in on telnet ... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: i just noticed that i am stupid, i installed telnet for windows, using control panel, and it just times out there

Comment: you stated `Using the cxlinux password, i get: -sh /bin/hostname: not found` - now you say it times out ... how can you get a response and a timeout?

Comment: IDK, my phone connects to it using JuiceSSH ( runs telnet too) and terminus, but my laptop cant. i just got my phone to get something, i gave it the command sudo, and it said -sh: sudo: not found        
.no help command, also, when i run ls, it takes slightly longer that commands like cd, so does it just have no files or directories?

Comment: just put in a random forward slash, and got permission denied, a backslash gives me a new first character, > instead of #, its not a python shell, as print just gives a syntax error, put print with the # start just gives command not found???????, clearly some different shell with different inputs

Comment: I did cd ..    and now i have some linux folders when running ls: i got: bin etc init linuxrc mnt opt proc run sys usr dev home lib media nfsroot p2pcam root sbin tmp var... p2pcam is probably the camera's software

Comment: just did ifconfig, turns out it has a eth0 interface, could the camera have a raspberry pi in it??

Comment: Oh sure, why not.

Comment: just did a teardown on it, it has some weird board, probably made just for the camera, im turning this one into a fake security camera, the other ones, ( i have 3 ) will be used for other testing, can you post an answer with the username root and password cxlinux so i can close the post.

Comment: nah, I don't think I'll post an answer. You're quite welcome to post your own answer

Comment: ok, if you do post a answer, you will probally get rep but ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password was cxlinux

Username was Root